# Android application for rendering MathML or LaTeX

Tags: math-software

I am looking for an android application that will allow entering equations with my cellphone in the correct format

Comment: You didn't mean mathjax, did you?

Comment: Yeah am i doing something wrong?

Comment: There is not a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of one for Android or Linux,
but this one works for me
on Mac OS X and (it says) Windows:
http://www.inkcode.net/qute